# Create a list with True or False

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I want to create a list that contains 5 elements that says `TRUE` as such

```
$`1`
[1] TRUE

$`2`
[1] TRUE

$`4`
[1] TRUE

$`7`
[1] TRUE

$`15`
[1] TRUE

$`22`
[1] TRUE
```

I tried `trlst <- (list(rep('True',5)))` ,but it gives me  `[[1]] [1] "True" "True" "True" "True" "True"`

What should I change to get the list in different levels.

Comment: Use `as.list(rep(T, 5))`.

Comment: `'True'` is a character object.  You need to use the `TRUE` logical object. `replicate` is a function that is also useful here, as in `replicate(n = 5, TRUE, simplify = FALSE)`

Comment: You could also use `rep(list(TRUE), 5)` which is more efficient than both of the above. That isn't particularly important for this example, but it may be important when working with larger lists.